blank screen react webpage not appearing
hi my react page does not appear please see if there is anything wrong with my code
program edited here it is now
index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
    <script type="module" src="./main.tsx"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>


main.tsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)


App.tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setTodos([...todos, input]);
    setInput('');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Todo" value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Add Todo</button>
      {todos.map((todo, index) => <p key={index}>{todo}</p>)}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

the screen is blank
i have saved all the files and refreshed the webpage but nothing is appearing
edit: an error is appearing in the console please see below
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

my file has a .tsx file format so i dont know why this is appearing

Is there an error in the console? Maybe some file is not being fetched, check the network tab as well

How are you running the server?

@mssp Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. my app has a .tsx so i dont know why this is appearing

@Phix running the server with create vite@latest , npm i and npm run dev

Put the script in <head> also make sure, that the path is correct, I think you are getting that error because of the path of the script is not correct. Try maybe ./main.tsx I am not sure where exactly is your config vite and your script located

Also you have an error here    <button onClick={()=>setTodos(input)}>Add Todo</button> which is unrelated to the issue you are facing, I corrected the error in your "Add Todo" button

i thought the script tag is always at the bottom of the html so that the javascript knows what to work with in the dom

Script needs to load first then the body gets loaded

made the adjustments still not working
